# CakePHP get record from another table if the id matches

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new to CakePHP and still learning as I make my way through each problem.

I have two tables: customers and stores. In stores table I have a foreign key called customer_id that holders customer id from customers table.

In CakePHP, I created controllers, models, and view for above tables. From CustomerController.php in view action, I am trying to get store that matches id of customer.

CustomerController.php page:

```
class CustomersController extends AppController
{

    public function index()
    {
        $customers = $this->Customers->find('all'); // Find all the records from the database.
        $this->set('customers', $customers);
        $stores = $this->Customers->Stores->find('all');
        $this->set('stores', $stores);        
    }

    public function view($id = NULL) 
    {
        $customer = $this->Customers->get($id); // Find a record for individual record.
        $this->set('customer', $customer);

        // $stores = $this->Customers->Stores->find('all');
        $stores = $this->Customers->Stores->find('list', [
                'keyField' => 'id',
                'valueField' => 'store_name'
            ]);        
        $this->set('store', $stores);
    }
}
```

SQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `customers`
--

INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`) VALUES
(1, 'Ray', 'Mak'),
(2, 'John', 'Smith'),
(3, 'Mike', 'Gorge');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `states`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `states` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `states`
--

INSERT INTO `states` (`id`, `state_name`) VALUES
(1, 'TX'),
(2, 'VA'),
(3, 'WI'),
(4, 'AZ'),
(5, 'FL');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `stores`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stores` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `corp_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `street_address` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zipcode` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `customers_idx` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `states_idx` (`state_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

View page:

```
<pre>
<?php 
print_r(json_encode($store));
print_r(h($customer));
?>
</pre>
```

I can use a custom SQL query with left join to get the results, but in cakephp its confusing how I can get data from another table when id matches.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: I think I solved my own problem. I was able to use conditions which took me a while to understand because the document on cakephp is not very clear when explaining things.

`$stores = $this->Customers->Stores->find('all',[ 'conditions' => array('Stores.id' => $id)]);`

Comment: and try $this->Customers->Stores->findById($id);

Comment: And read the manual section on [Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html). If you set up your models correctly (which would be done for you automatically if you use the Bake tool), your query in the customer view method should simply be `$this->Customers->get($id, ['contain' => ['Stores']]);`

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you so much for your solution and it works great. :) However, I am still confuse when to use contain. If I understand it correctly, your solution will get all the data that matches id from Stores model table col customer_id.

Answer (score 3):

Ray,

You have mentioned in comments that you resolved your issue, but if you are using the below code in CustomersController :: view function, then $id does not represent stores id.

```
$stores = $this->Customers->Stores->find('all',[ 'conditions' => array('Stores.id' => $id)]);
```

In order to get stores associated with customers, you must refer to below code

```
$stores = $this->Customers->Stores->findByCustomerId($id);
//where $id represents customer_id from stores table
```

Comment: Hi Manish, thank you very much for your response. Your solution works same as what I answered as my own solution. But when I run Greg's solution, I am able to print both Stores and Customer data in one associative array. But with your solution and mine, I have to print $store and $customer variable separately. Where as Greg's solution, I can get everything in one variable.